# find repeated words number in c++

Tags: c++

is there anyway to find out how many times a word repeated in a text .

the text is in character arrays (char[])

> text =  this is a book,and this book
>   is about book.
>
> word = book
>
> result = 3

Comment: Yes, this is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: homework detected.

Comment: What are your concrete requirements? How big will the text be? Will you perform a single query? Will you rather query for different words?

Comment: I guess the requirements are more about getting an 'A' or something like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is clearly homework and not tagged as such, I'll give you a solution you clearly can't submit as your assignment because your teacher will *know* you got it on the internet.

There were no requirements such as ignoring punctuation, so I've allowed myself to write a version that only works for clearly separated words and thus inserted spaces in your sample text string.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

    // Count clearly separated occurrences of `word` in `text`.
std::size_t count ( const std::string& text, const std::string& word )
{
    std::istringstream input(text);
    return (std::count(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(input),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(), word));
}

int main ( int, char ** )
{
    const char text[] = "this is a book , and this book is about book .";
    const char word[] = "book";
    std::cout << count(text, word) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> 3

Comment: I disagree that there were no requirements.  The one requirement provided is that given the example input, you can produce the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to implement this using `std::string` and [**here**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) is a sample for you to start from.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to loop through the string, counting the number of times that you find the word that you're looking for. I'm sure that you could use a function in `<algorithm>` to do it fairly easily, but if you have to ask whether it's possible to do this in C++, I wouldn't think that you're advanced enough to try using the algorithm library, and doing it yourself would be more instructional anyway.

I would suggest using `std::string` though if you're allowed to (since this question does sound like homework, which could carry additional restrictions). Using `std::string` is easier and less error-prone than char arrays. It can be done with both though.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

You have an array of characters. Try to do the search on a piece of paper, character by character:

> First character is a T. This is not a b, so it can't be the first character of "book"
>   Second character is a h, so again, it is not b...
>
> [...]
>
> The next character is a b... Oah, this could be it. Is the next character a o? YES!!! And then next another o???... etc. etc..

When you can do it this way, you will be able to use C++ to do it.

Remember that you can access the n-th character in an array by using the `[]` operator:

```
char c = array[5] ; // c is the 6th character in the array
```

Now, going toward the C++ way would be, at first, to use a std::string instead of an array of chars, and use the strings methods. Google for [`std::string methods`](http://www.google.com/search?q=std%3A%3Astring+methods), and I guess you should find somes that you could use...
So you should manage to write some code that will iterate each character until the end

I guess this should be more than enough.

The point of your homework (because everyone here knows this is a homework question) is more about searching for the solution than finding it: This is not rote learning.

I doubt anyone on Stack Overflow remembers the solution to this classical problem. But I guess most will know how to find one solution. **You need to learn the "how to find" mindset**, so get your compiler and try again...

P.S.: Of course, if you know little or nothing of C++, then you're screwed, and you could start by [`Googling some C++ Tutorials`](http://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+tutorial).